# How to give color to string in the java code of android?

Tags: android

How to give color to string:
Example:

```
String str="Hello Android";
```

How to give color to the above string?

Also how to give red color to string "cancel" the following :

```
final String[] items = { "Switch Off", "Timer Settings","Cancel"};
```

Comment: You mean in the app (and not in the IDE), right? Your question is a bit confusing...

Comment: are you using this strings to set text for Textview?

Comment: There is no way to that in string file. but you can do that by creating a [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and setting background of TextView

Comment: assuming you are using those strings for a textview, simply use the 'setTextColor(int)' method. Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)

Comment: Try making use of the styles in the Android and use these styles in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final CharSequence[] items = {
    "Switch Off",
    "Timer Settings",
    Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">Cancel</font>"),
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use spannable class to do this:

```
 Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(myString);        
            WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string use `TextView` and change the background of it e.g

```
  TextView tv;
  tv.setText("yourText");
  tv.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
```